# Import managed metadata to SharePoint via FME

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list, fme

I would like to use FME to import some data from excel (csv) to SharePoint list.

Is there a way to write the managed metadata with FME into a SharePoint list field?

I tried to write the textual data, also the lookup manually seem to work. However I have in CSV some text labels that corresponds to some managed metadata, and look if there is a way to import them via FME

**Example**

Say, I have to import in SharePoint a list of projects. The project State, is a SharePoint managed metadata, it has "Open", "Closed" and "Paused" entries. Each sharepoint managed metadata has its GUID internally.

Say I import from the CSV a project

Name,State,Date
"My Project",Open,02/06/2024 10:56

the "Open" should be interpreted as managed metadata, and used could select to pass it to "Close" etc...

Comment: Some code examples and experiments could help. Good questions always get more answers. Currently,  the question is broad and there is much to answer.

Comment: @CuriousWatcher I added an example